# Multisite Subdomain Change

Tags: multisite, subdomains

Hello I've started using the WordPress Multisite feature and my setup is this:
https://Blog.Website.com (Currently set as Main)
https://Blog.Help.Website.com

**I'm trying to change it to:**
https://Blog.Website.com (Should be set as Main)
https://Help.Website.com

Does WordPress Multisite support this setup?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create multisite on https://Blog.Website.com then you will get the result as same as https://Blog.Help.Website.com So, you should  create multi site with main website https://Website.com

then you will get the result as you expected.

https://Blog.Website.com

https://Help.Website.com

https://New.Website.com